# "Sorry, posts can't contain that content."

Tags: support, status-completed

Has anyone ever seen this before? I don't know why I got it (multiple times). There aren't any unintentional profanities that I'm aware of or anything...

[image: Sorry, Posts Can't Contain That Content.]

The links were to MSDN and a SharePoint blog at www.sharepointboost.com (don't know the site personally, but it was good follow up material.) The question I tried to answer on was [SPSecurity.CatchAccessDeniedException = false: Does Sharepoint keep this setting?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43364/spsecurity-catchaccessdeniedexception-false-does-sharepoint-keep-this-setting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link to SharePoint Boost is the problem. They have spammed our site consistently so all URLs from them are blocked.

Comment: Good to know. I just Googled instructions to set up anonymous access and found the first decent set of instructions.

Comment: I am honestly surprised they had a decent article on their site. ;)

Comment: It was probably scraped anyhow.